# Zip all subfolders inside a folder to individual zip file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, files, zip

I have around 200 folders right under a huge folder `Parent`, say as `child1-100`

-`Parent`

----`child1/contents`

----`child2/contents`

How do I change all the folders named `child 1-100` into each zip folder, such as `child1.zip, child2.zip`?
I tried doing this command `for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i"; done`
but it gave me `child1.zip` which after extracted gave `/child1/child1/contents`. I just want the zip file `child1.zip` to give `/child1/contents` folder after extracting.

Comment: Your code looks correct. You say "extracted gave /child1/child1/contents" -- what directory were you in when you extracted? The zip file will contain "child1/contents", verify with `unzip -l child1.zip`. If you did `cd child1; unzip ../child1.zip` then you will get the results you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the zip file to contain only `contents`, not `child1/contents`, then do this:

```
for dir in */; do
    ( cd "$dir" && zip -r ../"${dir%/}".zip . )
done
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Could you please explain what I was missing?

Comment: since zip preserves the directory structure, when you `zip -r x.zip dir`, the zip contains files named `dir/file1`, `dir/file2`, etc. If you don't want to keep that top level of the hierarchy, you need to descend into the directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in child*; do
    #recursive zip to include folder contents
    zip -r "${dir}.zip" "$dir"
done
```